# Codeigniter Issue With Default Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I have an apllication in php.But i created its admin panel in codeigniter.When i try to access admin panel it is not working correctly.

That means

`lensframes` is my root folder.In this folder i done the user panel of the site.Then i created a folder `Admin` and done the admin panel here using codeigniter.

In this `Admin` i changed the base_url() from config file.
then i changed the database file and also changed default controller as Admin in  routes.php.

Then i created a controller that is i created the `Admin.php` in the controller folder.

when i taking the url as

```
http://www.rapidsurfing.net/lensframes/Admin/
```

it displys error message

```
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.
```

but when iam taking url as

```
http://www.rapidsurfing.net/lensframes/Admin/index.php/Admin
```

I can access the admin panel.
What is the problem in my application?.The default controller is not working in my site.

Comment: IIRC: codeignighter needs apache's multiviews enabled. I would check that first.

Comment: i cant understand your solution explain detaily

Comment: You HAVE edited your `.htaccess` file, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder named 'admin' in your /application/controller folder. Then you can add controllers like normal, including a default controller if you go to http://www.rapidsurfing.net/lensframes/admin directly.

CodeIgniter supports a subfolder inside of the controller folder. You don't have to change the `base_url()`.